# Drag & Drop does not work for Win 10 Host and Ubuntu LTS 20.04 Guest on Oracle VirtualBox 6.1

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, drag-and-drop

Regarding the Drag & Drop function in Oracle VirtualBox 6.1.3.2.  In accordance with numerous online tutorials, I have done the following:

1. Installed Guest Additions on the Ubuntu LTS 20.04 Guest machine
2. Enabled bidirectional for Drag and Drop from the UI of VirtualBox Version 6.1.3.2.

However, when I attempt to drag files from WIn10 Host to Ubuntu Guest or Ubuntu Guest to Win10 Host, the cursor becomes a X symbol, indicating the action is illegal.

I've scoured the internet and YouTube, but whilst other people with diffrent OS guests and hosts, at different times and maybe in different versions have been able to achieve it, I can't seem to get it to work for Win 10 host and Ubuntu guest.

Comment: I solve this issue by mapping the Host drive in the guest and then drag between two file manager windows. That works.

Comment: Also, you have to make sure you can map the Host Drive before drag / drop will work.

Comment: Also, I found I can drag / drop between Windows Host and Windows Guest but not Linux Guests. I just map the drive and copy files that way.